# summing all possible left to right diagonals along specified columns in a data frame by group?

Tags: r

Suppose I have something like this:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1,2, 2, 2, 4,4,4,4,6,6,6), 
               binary1=c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
               binary2=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1),
               binary3=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0),
               binary4=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0))
```

I want to sum along all possible left to right diagonals within groups (i.e group 1, 2 4 and 6) and return the max sum. This is also in a dataframe, so I would like to specify to only sum along binary1-binary4. Anyone know if this is possible?

Here's my desired output:

```
   group binary1 binary2 binary3 binary4 want
1      1       1       0       0       0    2
2      1       0       1       0       0    2
3      2       1       0       0       0    3
4      2       0       1       0       0    3
5      2       0       0       1       0    3
6      4       0       1       0       0    3
7      4       0       0       1       0    3
8      4       0       0       0       1    3
9      4       0       0       0       0    3
10     6       0       0       0       0    1
11     6       0       1       0       0    1
12     6       0       1       0       0    1
```

I have circled the "diagonals" I would like summed for group 4 in this image as an example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the data.frame and sum the diagonal using diag(). Once you have this sum diagonal per group, it's putting them back into the data.frame by calling the group.

Group 4 should be zero? Or am I missing something:

```
DIAG = by(df[,-1],df$group,function(i)sum(diag(as.matrix(i))))
df$want = DIAG[as.character(df$group)]
```

If I get your definition correct, we define a function to calculate sum of main diagonal:

```
main_diag = function(m){
sapply(1:(ncol(m)-1),function(i)sum(diag(m[,i:ncol(m)])))
}
```

Thanks to @IceCreamToucan for correcting this. Then we consider the max of all main diagonals, and their transpose:

```
DIAG = by(df[,-1],df$group,function(i){
  i = as.matrix(i)
  max(main_diag(i),main_diag(t(i)))
})

df$want = DIAG[as.character(df$group)]

   group binary1 binary2 binary3 binary4 want
1      1       1       0       0       0    2
2      1       0       1       0       0    2
3      2       1       0       0       0    3
4      2       0       1       0       0    3
5      2       0       0       1       0    3
6      4       0       1       0       0    3
7      4       0       0       1       0    3
8      4       0       0       0       1    3
9      4       0       0       0       0    3
10     6       0       0       0       0    1
11     6       0       1       0       0    1
12     6       0       1       0       0    1
```

Comment: group 4 has three 1's starting from binary2-binary4 that are diagonal, I'm not concerned with the start point

Comment: I will clarify in the post then

Comment: This takes the sum of the main diagonal. In the example data the main diagonal always has the largest sum, but if that's not true, e.g. if the second-to-last value of binary1 is changed to 1, the `want` column will be different from the max diagonal sum.

Comment: Hi @IceCreamToucan, thanks so much for pointing it out! I forgot about the transpose. I have edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution where we use `row` and `col` indices to get all possible combinations of diagonals. Use `by` to split by group and `merge` it with original dataframe.

```
max_diag <- function(x) max(sapply(split(as.matrix(x), row(x) - col(x)), sum))

merge(df, stack(by(df[-1], df$group, max_diag)), by.x = "group", by.y = "ind")

#   group binary1 binary2 binary3 binary4 values
#1      1       1       0       0       0      2
#2      1       0       1       0       0      2
#3      2       1       0       0       0      3
#4      2       0       1       0       0      3
#5      2       0       0       1       0      3
#6      4       0       1       0       0      3
#7      4       0       0       1       0      3
#8      4       0       0       0       1      3
#9      4       0       0       0       0      3
#10     6       0       0       0       0      1
#11     6       0       1       0       0      1
#12     6       0       1       0       0      1
```

Comment: nice row-col and in addition, this one seems more correct for e.g. in group 7: `df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1,2, 2, 2, 4,4,4,4,6,6,6,7,7), 
    binary1=c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
    binary2=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0),
    binary3=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
    binary4=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))`

Comment: This is great, however is there a way to specify just summing the binary vars (i.e. if I have lots of other char vars between binary1 and group?) I could merge these vars in after but would prefer not to

Comment: @biostatguy12 You can select the required columns `merge(df, stack(by(df[2:5], df$group, max_diag)), by.x = "group", by.y = "ind")`